# Function for removing vowels from a character

Tags: python-3.x

Define a function called anti_vowel that takes one string, text, as input and returns the text with all of the vowels removed.

For example, anti_vowel("Hey You!") should return "Hy Y!". Don't count Y as a vowel. Make sure to remove lowercase and uppercase vowels.

```
def anti_vowel(text):
  b=""
  for i in text:
    print i
    for j in "aeiouAEIOU":
      if i!=j:
        b+=i
        break
  return b
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please learn how to debug. Put a breakpoint on the inner loop and trace it. Or just print trace information for the `if` statement. Also `print i` is invalid in py3

Answer (score 0):

You should check using in.

```
If i not in "aeiouAEIOU":
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but I wanted to know what I am doing wrong

Comment: In most cases your condition is true. Take a look


    print(i, j, i!=j)
    ('H', 'a', True)
    ('e', 'a', True)
    ('y', 'a', True)
    (' ', 'a', True)
    ('Y', 'a', True)
    ('o', 'a', True)
    ('u', 'a', True)
    ('!', 'a', True)